# utf-16 file seeking in python. how?

Tags: python, utf-16

For some reason i can not seek my utf16 file. It produces 'UnicodeException: UTF-16 stream does not start with BOM'. My code:

```
f = codecs.open(ai_file, 'r', 'utf-16')
seek = self.ai_map[self._cbClass.Text]  #seek is valid int
f.seek(seek)
while True:
    ln = f.readline().strip()
```

I tried random stuff like first reading something from stream, didnt help. I checked offset that is seeked to using hex editor - string starts at character, not null byte (i guess its good sign, right?)
So how to seek utf-16 in python?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Well, the error message is telling you why: it's not reading a byte order mark. The byte order mark is at the beginning of the file. Without having read the byte order mark, the UTF-16 decoder can't know what order the bytes are in. Apparently it does this lazily, the first time you read, instead of when you open the file -- or else it is assuming that the `seek()` is starting a new UTF-16 stream.

If your file doesn't have a BOM, that's definitely the problem and you should specify the byte order when opening the file (see #2 below). Otherwise, I see two potential solutions:

1. Read the first two bytes of the file to get the BOM before you seek. You seem to say this didn't work, indicating that perhaps it's expecting a fresh UTF-16 stream after the seek, so:
2. Specify the byte order explicitly by using `utf-16-le` or `utf-16-be` as the encoding when you open the file.